# Why my Chrome extensions may have been corrupted?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

AdBlocker, Norton Id-Safe and more extensions does not work any more? why?

> AdBlock 2.17     This extension may have been corrupted.

I click on repair but it does not work. How do I reinstall them again?

Comment: I have no idea what this message actually means, but `chkdsk` can’t hurt. :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `chrome://extensions/` find the one that doesnt work, **AdBlock** in your case and click on little garbage icon to remove it. Than go to chrome web store and add [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) again

*If this happened on chrome update, you should check is it issue with chrome*

So check for your version of chrome chrome://help/ Current version (as of Jan 25, 2015) is **40.0.2214.91** and on this one adblock is working fine. (maybe you didnt update your chrome)

- Try to clear cache, with Chrome and with CCleaner, to remove all app data and install AdBlock again
- Try to remove all extensions and add them one by one, to check if some of them is making problems
- or try clean install of google chrome.
- Downgrade Chrome to previous version where everything was working fine

I would definitely run CCleaner, or some similar tool to clean cache and fix some registry issues.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work.. I tried several times @malakrsnaslava

Comment: You cannot remove exstension, or you cannt add it back ?

Comment: I did removw them and I did add them back.. but still the same

Comment: so what is your google chrome version and your OS?

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall Google Chrome from your PC and re-install it, add the add-ons again and it will work.

{edit}
To un-install it completely go to control panel>programs>unistall or change a program> From there uninstall the google chrome.
Even delete the installation file from the downloads folder that won't matter but its your choice.
Open https://www.google.co.in/chrome/browser/desktop/ and download it from here. And install it, and add the add-ons.

This will work in case this not works, there might be some problem in your computer, clean it up if not.

Comment: I did it.. does not work..

Comment: Okay  you re-download the file, from the Google chrome's website and install it from the newly downloaded file. Sorry but this is the last option and I hope this will solve your problem too.  And chekc the edit i made in my answer may that help.

Comment: I will give you a perfect procedure to clean up the system, tell me in case you want or this doesn't work.